# Find every third value and insert cr or newline in VIM

Tags: python, vim

So I have several large datasets that I need to make more readable and currently I'm having to go in and move to each 3rd value and insert a newline. I've tried several things in VIM to get this to work, but none seem to return the value that I'm looking for. Here's some of my data:

```
(0.96260310749184663, 4.3830008206495812, 0.84922658632317849),
(0.96260310749184663, 5.0000002088986637, 1.049701855818201),
(0.96260310749184697, 5.6169993576359696, 0.8492264385213405),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.9983257940402384, 0.32437568665165911),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.9983258053918069, -0.32437572732698844),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.6169994358349786, -0.84922691097323821),
(0.96260310749184697, 5.0000000093711492, -1.0497019267383632)
```

What I need to do is make it look like this instead:

```
(0.96260310749184663, 4.3830008206495812, 
 0.84922658632317849),
(0.96260310749184663, 5.0000002088986637, 
 1.049701855818201),
(0.96260310749184697, 5.6169993576359696, 
 0.8492264385213405),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.9983257940402384, 
 0.32437568665165911),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.9983258053918069, 
 -0.32437572732698844),
(0.96260310749184719, 5.6169994358349786, 
 -0.84922691097323821),
(0.96260310749184697, 5.0000000093711492, 
 -1.0497019267383632)
```

I used this on a selection to try and get it to move that 3rd value down, but it duplicated the entire thing and then moved the entire line down:

```
:'<,'>s/\([-[0-9.]\+,\s[-[0-9.]\+,\)/\1\r&/g
```

I also tried removing the 1 to make it work, but that didn't work either. So is there any way I can capture that 3rd value and insert a carriage return or newline to make this work? Thanks.

Edit---

I apologize for mis-communicating part of my problem: The data at the top is all on one line, not several lines. It looks like this:

```
(0.31852533878680489, 0.10352149350126813, -0.0046069731261429991), (0.31852526554320226, -0.103521543762028, -0.0046069731261429991), (0.19682845687859715, -0.27102285045297636, -0.004606973126142444), (-8.1184530326649769e-05, -0.33500267513407755, -0.0046069731261416669), (-0.19699089317458821, -0.27102292369657782, -0.0046069731261408897), (-0.31868770183919259, -0.10352150714022559, -0.0046069731261403346), (-0.31868770183919221, 0.10352156674487166, -0.0046069731261403346),
```

Comment: I'd argue the second form is not really more readable than the first.

Comment: I would agree, however, we're attempting to stick to a less than 80 character width since many of us have multiple files open at once in a single session. More of an internal thing than a "look better" thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:g/./norm! 2Wi^M
```

Explanation:

- `:g/./{cmd}` will run the `{cmd}` on every line
- `norm!` will execute the following string as normal mode commands
- `2Wi^M` Move 2 `WORDS` then insert a return
- `^M` is accomplished by pressing `<c-v><cr>` or `<c-q><cr>`.

It is very tempting to do `%norm! 2Wi^M`, but this will fail as it messes up the lines that are being worked on.

Comment: That replaces my text with this: (-8.1164565363906472e-05, ^M0.33500269811692118, -0.0046069731261416669),

Comment: `^M` is not a literal `^M` you need to press `<c-v>` followed by a `<cr>` or enter key. `:h i_Ctrl-V`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Still getting used to VIM. It worked great, but only on a single line, thus why the other answer was chosen as accepted, but this will definitely help me in my workflow.

Comment: Just add a substitution and delete the last line. `:s/),\s*/),\r/g|$d_|g/./norm! 2Wi^M`

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for. You sir, rock.

Comment: Note that performance of this command is not high (especially on large files).  Consider [using `:substitte` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7721025#7721025) as a faster alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Two approaches

#### 1. ex commands and formatting

My first thought was `textwidth`:

```
:se tw=50
:g/./norm! gqq
:%s/^[^(]/ &/g
```

This

1. sets text width to 50 chars
2. reformats each (nonempty) line
3. inserts a space at the start of any lines which don't start with `(`

#### 2. use a macro

Alternatively: make a macro

```
gg
qq2f,a<CR><Esc>j0q
100000@q
```

Rationale:

1. go to begin of buffer
2. record macro `q` (`qq` starts recording, `q` ends recording)

   - `2f,` - forward to second comma
   - `a<CR><Esc>` - append newline
   - `j0` - next line, move caret to first character
3. rinse and repeat (100000 is the number of times to repeat; processing will stop when the macro fails (e.g. at end of file)

Comment: I get an `E16: Invalid range` error in MacVim with your macro solution. I have done an alternate recursive macro way to do it that circumvents the error.

Comment: @Jin: that's strange. MacVim should behave portably. Perhaps there is an option that I'm not aware of. I do this all the time. You _did_ enter `10000@q` (whatever the number) in _normal mode_, did you?

Comment: Oooops, I entered it in command mode. Your solution works! My bad. And I also learnt about recursive macros myself today. +1 to ya.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. Had to go in and manually move some of it down and about, but it worked great. I ended up using: qq2Wi<cr><esc> since my data was all on one line and then ran it 1000 times.

Comment: I like your first approach!  However, its second command definitely has an error.  I think, it should be `:g/./norm!gqq`.

Comment: Macro solution is good, too.  (By the way, why don't you use a recursive macro?)  Note, though, that its performance (especially on large files) is not high.  I would suggest [using `:substitte` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7721025#7721025) as a much faster alternative.

Comment: @ib.: as I commented at [Jin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7714512#7714512) "I didn't know you could do a recurse macro. I'm not sure whether I'd want to use it recursively though. It seems easier to get right, test, and control in non-recursive form"

Answer (score 2):

Since the entire text to break is in one line initially, one can use a single
short substitution command,

```
:s/,.\{-},\|), /&\r/g
```

Comment: @sehe:  There is no mistake in the fact that the `:substitute` command operates on a single line here.  It is intended to do so, since the whole text to transform is in one line.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this would be something like this:

```
'<,'>s/^[^,]\+,[^,]\+,\zs/\r
```

Translated:

```
'<,'>     " Over the visual range
s/X/Y     " Substitute X with Y
^         " Start of line
[^,]\+    " Anything that isn't a comma, one or more, as many as possible
,         " A comma (end of first field)
[^,]\+    " Anything that isn't a comma, one or more again
,         " A comma (send of second field)
\zs       " Mark this point as the start of the match so we don't have to bother including all of the above in the result
\r        " We're replacing nothing at the end of the above match with a new-line (\r)
```

---

Another alternative:

```
'<,'>s/^\(.\{-},\)\{2}/&\r
```

Translated:

```
'<,'>s/X/Y     " As before
^              " Start of line
\(...\)        " A group containing:
.\{-},         " Everything up to and including the first comma
\{2}           " Match the preceding group twice (so up to and including the second comma)
&\r            " Replace with what was already there followed by a new-line
```

---

And another... given that you have equal data widths, navigate to the space before the third column of the first row.  Hit `Ctrl-V` and go down so that you've selected the whole column of spaces (`6j` in your example).  Press either `s` or `Shift-i` (depending on whether you want to keep the space) and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use the macros to format a line and go to the begining of the next line. Then apply that macro as may times as you need.

So, starting to record a macro is `q_` where `_` is a register, then edit your line, press `q` again to save the macro. And finally, apply it using `@_` which you can prefix with a number of times you want to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive macro (as an alternative to @sehe's macro-for-100000-times answer).

`ggqa2f,a<CR><Esc>j@aq`

Then `@a` to run the command on the second line (you shouldn't need to move your cursor).

Visualization:

`gg`

[image]

`qa`

[image]

`2f,`

[image]

`a<Cr><Esc>`

[image]

`j@aq`

[image]

`@a`

[image]

Comment: Funny; you came up with exactly the same macro. I didn't know you could do a recurse macro. I'm not sure whether I'd want to use it recursively though. It seems easier to get right, test, and control in non-recursive form

Comment: Hey - I see you edited your answer. What's the rationale behind using a recursive macro **and** using a range-based ex command at the same time? I'd think that starting the macro on the first line would be enough?

Comment: @sehe yes, I just realized that. Edited!

Comment: In fact, there is a problem with using `:%` with command that affects the buffer linecount. Witness: `:let @a="2f,a<CR><Esc>"`, `:%norm @a` only transforms part of the document

Comment: @sehe Yup, that was the problem I met when coming up with the macro on the first time. Hmm, a downvote..

Comment: Wow you've done quite a job at presenting your answer. +1 for the effort