# How to break lines before one column?

Tags: unix, vim

I want to insert return before one column of multiple lines, so I select the characters of this column with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in normal mode, then type `I`, Vim enters insert mode. After typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and press key <kbd>Esc</kbd>, only one line is broken. Is there any way to perform this function? Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [Find every third value and insert cr or newline in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7714512#7714512)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To break lines just before a particular column, use `\%v` search pattern atom
that matches in a given position with zero-width (see `:help /\%v`).  The
following example command inserts new line character between the seventh and
the eighth columns.

```
:%s/\%8v/\r/
```

This idea could be extended to use the number of the column where the cursor
is currently located.

```
:exe'%s/\%'.virtcol('.').'v/\r/'
```

The commands above does not require neither of those columns to be selected.
However, if it is easier for you to specify the split column with blockwise
Visual mode, use `\%V` zero-width atom matching inside the selected area (see
`:help \%V`).

```
:'<,'>s/\%V/\r/
```

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty solution - first, insert some character which is not in column (say, #) , then, `gv`, then `'<,'>s/#/\r/g`.

will be glad if one provide more clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the desired lines, to break on third column:

```
:'<,'>g/./norm! 3|a^M
```

(`^M` inserted by pressing `<c-v><CR>` or `<c-q><CR>`)

, similar to answer on [Find every third value and insert cr or newline in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7714682#7714682)

Comment: This command feels a little bit overcomplicated.  In addition, its performance is noticeably lower than in case of [plain substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724089/how-to-break-lines-before-one-column/7725184#7725184).  By the way, it also applies to the command proposed in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7714682#7714682) you link to: [the solution using substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714278/find-every-third-value-and-insert-cr-or-newline-in-vim/7721025#7721025) is much faster.